# Get full path to a NSPathControl selected file

Tags: objective-c, nspathcontrol

I have a NSPathControl in my app for the user to select a file on his hard disk.

I am trying to use

```
-(IBAction) clickedPath:(id) sender {

NSString *string=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[[pathControl clickedPathComponentCell] stringValue]];

NSLog (@"%@", string);

}
```

But this outputs only the filename. How can I get the full path to the file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the URL property:

```
- NSString *string=[[pathControl URL] path];
```